# Magento controller override not working in other systems

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers, cms-block, admin-controller

I have installed `Magento CE 1.9.2.4` in my local system.

Now I have successfully overrided the `Admin >> CMS >> Static Block controller` in my local system in such a way that when I save any static_block it displays message `The block <block_identifier> was saved.`

But when I install this module into server or some other system, it doesn't work at all.

Below are my module files:
magento_root/app/etc/modules
module-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CmsBlocks>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml/>
                <Mage_Cms/>
            </depends>
        </Company_CmsBlocks>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Module config.xml
magento_root/app/code/local/Company/CmsBlocks/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CmsBlocks>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_CmsBlocks>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml><!--This should be same as defined in Mage_Adminhtml config.xml-->
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_CmsBlocks before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_CmsBlocks</Company_CmsBlocks>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Module controller:
magento_root/app/code/local/Company/CmsBlocks/controllers/Adminhtml/BlockController.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Cms manage blocks controller
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */

require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php';
## require_once 'home/kaffewebex/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php';
## require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Cms' . DS . 'BlockController.php');

class Company_CmsBlocks_Adminhtml_BlockController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_BlockController
{
    /**
     * Init actions
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_BlockController
     */
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('cms/block')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('cms')->__('CMS'), Mage::helper('cms')->__('CMS'))
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Static Blocks'), Mage::helper('cms')->__('Static Blocks'))
        ;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('CMS'))->_title($this->__('Static Blocks'));

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Create new CMS block
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        // the same form is used to create and edit
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    /**
     * Edit CMS block
     */
    public function editAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('CMS'))->_title($this->__('Static Blocks'));

        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block');

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (! $model->getId()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('This block no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->_title($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : $this->__('New Block'));

        // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (! empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
        Mage::register('cms_block', $model);

        // 5. Build edit form
        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addBreadcrumb($id ? Mage::helper('cms')->__('Edit Block') : Mage::helper('cms')->__('New Block'), $id ? Mage::helper('cms')->__('Edit Block') : Mage::helper('cms')->__('New Block'))
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        // check if data sent
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id');
            $blockIdentifier = $data['identifier'];
            $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('This block no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

            // init model and set data

            $model->setData($data);

            // try to save it
            try {
                // save the data
                $model->save();
                // display success message
                ## Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__('The block has been saved.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__('The block "%s" has been saved.', $blockIdentifier));
                // clear previously saved data from session
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

                // check if 'Save and Continue'
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('block_id' => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                // go to grid
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // display error message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                // save data in session
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                // redirect to edit form
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('block_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * Delete action
     */
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        // check if we know what should be deleted
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id')) {
            $title = "";
            try {
                // init model and delete
                $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
                $model->load($id);
                $title = $model->getTitle();
                $model->delete();
                // display success message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__('The block has been deleted.'));
                // go to grid
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // display error message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                // go back to edit form
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('block_id' => $id));
                return;
            }
        }
        // display error message
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Unable to find a block to delete.'));
        // go to grid
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * Check the permission to run it
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('cms/block');
    }
}
```

Could this be related PHP include path not defined in some systems ?

Comment: may be the problem with `CmsBlocks` upper case word in module name did you change and try that change that to `Cmsblocks`. may be that is problem in your code.

Comment: It works in my system (Ubuntu) but doesn't work in my collegue's system (Ubuntu).

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Umpteen number of times and also session.

Comment: module is listed in admin panel?

Comment: Yes module is listed in my system, my collegue's system and also in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested and working

use   `Adminhtml` in override controller path

```
<modules><Company_CmsBlocks before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Cmsblocks_Adminhtml</Company_CmsBlocks></modules>
```

and `controller path` must be same after `Adminhtml`

`Company/Cmsblocks/Adminhtml/Cms/BlockController.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Cms manage blocks controller
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */

require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php';
## require_once 'home/kaffewebex/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php';
## require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Cms' . DS . 'BlockController.php');

class Company_Cmsblocks_Adminhtml_Cms_BlockController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_BlockController
{
    /**
     * Init actions
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_BlockController
     */
    protected function _initAction()
    { 
        // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('cms/block')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('cms')->__('CMS'), Mage::helper('cms')->__('CMS'))
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Static Blocks'), Mage::helper('cms')->__('Static Blocks'))
        ;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    { 
        $this->_title($this->__('CMS'))->_title($this->__('Static Blocks'));

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Create new CMS block
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        // the same form is used to create and edit
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    /**
     * Edit CMS block
     */
    public function editAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('CMS'))->_title($this->__('Static Blocks'));

        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block');

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (! $model->getId()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('This block no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->_title($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : $this->__('New Block'));

        // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (! empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
        Mage::register('cms_block', $model);

        // 5. Build edit form
        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addBreadcrumb($id ? Mage::helper('cms')->__('Edit Block') : Mage::helper('cms')->__('New Block'), $id ? Mage::helper('cms')->__('Edit Block') : Mage::helper('cms')->__('New Block'))
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        // check if data sent
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id');
            $blockIdentifier = $data['identifier'];
            $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('This block no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

            // init model and set data

            $model->setData($data);

            // try to save it
            try {
                // save the data
                $model->save();
                // display success message
                ## Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__('The block has been saved.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__('The block "%s" has been saved.', $blockIdentifier));
                // clear previously saved data from session
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

                // check if 'Save and Continue'
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('block_id' => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                // go to grid
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // display error message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                // save data in session
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                // redirect to edit form
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('block_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * Delete action
     */
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        // check if we know what should be deleted
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('block_id')) {
            $title = "";
            try {
                // init model and delete
                $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
                $model->load($id);
                $title = $model->getTitle();
                $model->delete();
                // display success message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__('The block has been deleted.'));
                // go to grid
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // display error message
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                // go back to edit form
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('block_id' => $id));
                return;
            }
        }
        // display error message
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Unable to find a block to delete.'));
        // go to grid
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * Check the permission to run it
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('cms/block');
    }
}
```